# JS get Maximum Value and Selected Value of Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of Drop down list in my page which has different values like some has values Starting like "NA, 1,2,3 to 100" other has "NA, 1 ,2,3 to 50" and other have different ending value but all are starting with "NA"

i am writing code to find the sum of the values selected and percentage of each value in JS.

The sum I got it the addition of selected values but percentage I am not getting. **I want to fetch the maximum value of the selected drop down list.**

JS Function

```
    function sum() {
      var result = 0;
      var sval = 0;

      for (var f = 1; f<= 5; f++) {
        var sval = document.getElementById('ddlist_'+f).value;
        if(!isNaN(sval)) {
          var sval = parseFloat(sval);
          result = result + sval;

        }
      }


      }
    }

    window.onload = sum;

Total Value of the Selected List is in Var Result. 
I want to find the Maximum value of all list
```

Example Drop Down list

```
    <option value=NA> NA </option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option>
```

output

```
<span id="maxtotal " style="color:#06F; font-weight:bold;"></span>
```

**In short, when Drop down list selected, I want to fetch the Selected Value and Last which is Maximum value of the Drop down List.**

Thanks you

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: JSBin: http://jsbin.com/sudom/1/edit.

Comment: Thank you Klaster for your effor to post on jsbin. I will wait for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `options` collection of an [`HTMLSelectElement` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) like an array.

```
function sum() {
  var $ = function (str) { return document.getElementById(str); },
      f, ddlist, sval, mval,
      result = 0, maxtotal = 0, percent;

  // try 'ddlist1', 'ddlist2', .. and so on
  f = 1;
  while (ddlist = $('ddlist' + f++)) {
    sval = ddlist.options[ddlist.selectedIndex].value;
    mval = ddlist.options[ddlist.options.length - 1].value;
    if ( !isNaN(sval) && !isNaN(mval) ) {
      result += parseFloat(sval);
      maxtotal += parseFloat(mval);
    }
  }

  percent = (maxtotal > 0) ? result / maxtotal * 100 : 0;

  $('maxtotal').innerHTML = result + ' of ' + maxtotal;
  $('totalper').innerHTML = percent.toFixed(2) + ' %';
}
```

Comment: Hello Dear, could you please have a look, its not working now. for your easy i put it here http://jsbin.com/sudom/14/

Comment: My mistake, the `$` function was the problem. Fixed above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to acomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/jK5Uq/

There is no trick here, I barely change anything to your code (the original version) but the html part:

```
<select id='ddlist_1' onchange='sum()'>
    <option value=NA> NA </option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id='ddlist_2' onchange='sum()'>
    <option value=NA> NA </option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select id='ddlist_3' onchange='sum()'>
    <option value=NA> NA </option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
</select>
<select id='ddlist_4' onchange='sum()'>
    <option value=NA> NA </option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
<p id="maxtotal" />
<p id="totalper" />
```