# JS Select Value and Last Value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Code, I want to select the selected value and last value of the drop down list in the JS function.

i am writing code to find the sum of the values selected and percentage of each value in JS.

The sum I got it the addition of selected values but percentage I am not getting. I want to fetch the maximum value of the selected drop down list

In short, when Drop down list selected, I want to fetch the Selected Value and Last which is Maximum value of the Drop down List.

The Code is here, its not wroking. Please let me know whats wrong in it.

**EDIT
I solve this, but its working in IE not in Chrome. Please let me know why .. its here http://jsbin.com/sudom/44**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? sum, average and maximum of two value?

Comment: I want to get the sum of the selected values and percentage of the selected value which is select/maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value is 100 in your case so you dont have to find it each time.As for the selected value try:

```
var temp = document.getElementById("ddlist1");
var selectedValue = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
```

For get the last value try:

```
var lastValue = temp.options[temp.options.length - 1].value;
```

Or if you use jquery you can try:

```
var lastValue = $('#ddlist1 option:last-child').val();
```

UPDATED:
Try this script

```
  function sum() {
  var f, ddlist, sval, mval,
      result = 0, maxtotal = 0, percent;

  // try 'ddlist1', 'ddlist2', .. and so on
  f = 1;
  while (ddlist = document.getElementById('ddlist' + f++)) {

    sval = ddlist.options[ddlist.selectedIndex].value;
    mval = ddlist.options[ddlist.options.length - 1].value;

    if ( !isNaN(sval) && !isNaN(mval) ) {
      result += parseFloat(sval);
      maxtotal += parseFloat(mval);
    }
  }

  percent = (maxtotal > 0) ? result / maxtotal * 100 : 0;

  document.getElementById('maxtotal').innerHTML = result + ' of ' + maxtotal;
  document.getElementById('totalper').innerHTML = percent.toFixed(2) + ' %';
}
```

Comment: I have different drop down list which has different maximum value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720034/js-get-maximum-value-and-selected-value-of-drop-down-list You can find my previsous question here

Comment: If you check the jsbin i have done the same thing. but its not calcualting.

Comment: can you pls check if there is any error in the code

Comment: I think I have to add some library. Do you know which I can ?

Comment: I solve this, but its working in IE not in Chrome. Please let me know why .. its here http://jsbin.com/sudom/44

Comment: Yes thank you.. its the same i Wanted to find out... thanks for your time... but can you say in my case it shwoing only in IE not in chrome...

Comment: I just tried @amudhan3093 (in jsbin) code and it worked/works in chrome. You could try "onchange" event instead of "blur" just to make it more user friendly.

Comment: Good allende thanks for tip... and amudhan i will use your code only.. its easily worked. But you knwo I have soem problem also befire. Some code work in IE not in Chrome... I dont know why